# Wordpress: permission denied on /wp-admin after server migration

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services

I'm currently trying to migration my multisite wordpress installation from ionos to aws.
On ionos, I have a single ubuntu server with plesk, nginx, apache, php 7.2.28, letsencrypt and mariadb.
On AWS, I have an ELB (doing the ssl termination), an amazon linux 2 (based on centos) instance with apache / php 7.2.34 / wordpress and another instance for mariadb.
I took a DB dump from production and restored it (untouched) on this new environment (same domain as production, accessed locally by modifying the `/etc/hosts` file).
I copied our wordpress codebase from production, modified the apache config file to fit the new folder structure and modified wp-config to reach the new DB instance and to stop forcing the ssl redirection.
The landing page works, I can access the website and the public pages, but when I try to login, it says permission denied ("Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.").
It seems like the authentication works because I can see the admin-bar on top of the homepage. When I try to access a page inside the wp-admin, I get the aforementionned error.
While debugging the code, I found out that the global $current_user has an ID of 0 when accessed from the function `user_can_access_admin_page`.

Here are the debugging details with the attempt to access the https://mydomain.tld/wp-admin/widgets.php page:

- The error is thrown by menu.php (https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/menu.php#L350) because `user_can_access_admin_page` returns false.
- Inside the `user_can_access_admin_page` function (https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/efaa79d347fbac1f9c4d1bc0494ec809b43e7042/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L2094), the current_user_can function is called, which itself calls the `wp_get_current_user` function which tries to retrieve the user from the global variable $current_user.
- Unfortunately, this variable doesn't contain the details about my current user (the $current_user->ID is set to 0 as if I'm not logged-in). On the homepage, I can see the admin-bar  with my username at the top of the page (which means that I am indeed logged in).

What's weird is that it works on production and I can't understand what's different between these two environments. Like I said, DB is exactly the same, codebase is the same, the only change I made is adding the following code at the bottom of wp-config to deal with ssl termination properly

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
       $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

`phpinfo()` shows that both servers have the same libraries installed.
I thought that the issue could be due to a different key/salt in wp-config than the one used to store the encrypted passwords, but they are the same as the one on production.
I've read the the global $current_user can be 0 if the init hook is not finished, but I doubt this is the case:

- it works on production
- this is part of the wordpress standard codebase

I've checked the permission for my user in the DB: it is a superadmin, has the level 10 with manage-network capabilities (and like I said, it's the same DB as prod, where it works fine)

I checked the file/folder permissions and they seem fine.

Comment: If $current_user is 0, and permission is denied, it seems likely that you're not logged in. It could be a cache problem that causes the admin bar to show.

Comment: I can login properly (and logout as well). When I debug on the landing page, I can see that $current_user is populated correctly with the data of my user.

Comment: Hi @NicolasRTT It's an weird bug and very hard to provide solution without debugging on the installation. I'm willing to assist you to debug the issue. Please DM me via skype live:rsm0128

Comment: For your information, WordPress uses cookie to authenticate. So please check the URL first for the admin page. Double confirm http|https and domain name first.

Comment: It sounds like your MS is folder, not domain, right? Are you trying to log into the "root site" or a sub-site, and regardless, can you get into any? Otherwise, I'd start looking at plugins next, especially any MU ones. Use the [CLI](https://wp-cli.org/) to start deactivating them and see if anything changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers, I'll investigate the cookie thing. I can't access the admin page at the moment, since I have this permission denied error on every wp-admin page.

Comment: @Chengmin I was able to fix the issue, you were right, that was (probably) an issue with the cookies. In the end, I had to skip the ELB and have the SSL on the same instance, used by both nginx and apache (don't ask! :D). Thanks a lot for your help. If you want to create an anwer, I'd be happy to give you the bounty.

Comment: It's great you fixed the issue and my suggestion helped you. Posted my suggestion as an answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

WordPress uses cookie to authenticate.
So please check the URL first for the admin page.
And then double confirm http|https and domain name first.

Comment: Thanks @Chengmin, as stated previously, this did the trick, wordpress was checking at the http cookie instead of the https. I removed the ELB (unfortunately) and it worked.